# How to specify this random image script

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript to show a random image on click:

```
function pickimg(){
var imagenumber = 4 ;
var randomnumber = Math.random() ;
var rand1 = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1;
images = new Array
images[1] = "images/1.png"
images[2] = "images/2.png"
images[3] = "images/3.png"
images[4] = "images/4.png"
var image = images[rand1]
document.randimg.src = image
```

Is there a way to make sure that the same image doesn't show up twice in a row?

Comment: You can create an array and do `array.search(image) != -1`

Comment: You could keep the current element and check if it's the same

Answer (score 0):

How 'bout this little alogrithm:

1. store the last used image in slot 0 of the array
2. choose a random image whose index is larger than 0.
3. display it
4. replace it with the image in slot 0

Javascript:

```
 images = new Array();
 images[0] = "images/1.png" //will be that last used image
 images[1] = "images/2.png"
 images[2] = "images/3.png"
 images[3] = "images/4.png"
 function pickimg(){
     var randomnumber = Math.random();
     // pick a random number from 1 to LENGTH (3)
     var rand1 = Math.round( (images.length-1) * randomnumber)+1;
     var image = images[rand1]; //get the image

    // switch so that the random image will be in the used
    // images slot (slot 0)
    images[rand1] = images[0] 
    images[0] = image 

    document.randimg.src = image
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems to work, but sometimes it gives a blank image saying 'Undefined'?